# Manual installation of Sqoop 1.4 on AWS EMR 5.5.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, sqoop, emr

I have launched a hadoop EMR Cluster (5.5.0 - components - Hive, Hue) but not SQOOP. But now i need to have sqoop also to query and dump data from mysql database. Since the cluster is already launched with good amount of data wanted to know if i can also add Sqoop. I dont see this option on AWS Console.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed it manually, done the required configuration. The limitation i guess now would be that if i have to clone the cluster then it wont be available.